# In Eclipse Neon, opening .fxml file with Scene Builder 8.2 always asks to install Scene Builder

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Good day folks, I have Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 installed as well as Scene Builder 8.2.0. I have eclipse pointing to the the executable for the Scene Builder but each time I try and "Open with SceneBuilder" it prompts me to install again ... when I've already installed. Is there something I'm missing? If I continue, installing the product again, it does appear after but the fxml file I wanted to edit does not load. No errors are present either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out when pointing my JavaFX via the Windows --> Preferences --> JavaFX to the Scene Builder executable, I was pointing it to the executable to install the product ... duh! I couldn't find Scene Builder in my Program Files folders so I thought one merely had to use the .exe that was downloaded as the installer.

I followed the shortcut created in the start menu to find the executable and all is good now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the Scenebuilder.exe file -> install it-> it will generate another .exe file -> through settings(for me INTELLIJ) direct the JAVAFX to the 2nd Scenebuilder.exe file.